# Trying to split array list of strings get warning @NonNull String regex Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, split

I am trying to load a file from a previously saved values from an editText. On the next load I am trying to make the fields populated with the previously entered data using split to get everything on that line after the split, as seen in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWchg.png). For some reason every time I try and split with .split("Name") everything between the quotation marks goes black instead of green and I get that @NonNull.

```
    public void loadList(){
    loadText = new ArrayList<String>();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    File file = new File (path + "/personalProfile.txt");
    try{
        editText_name.setText("");
        editText_dob.setText("");
        editText_mobile.setText("");
        editText_journal.setText("");
        editText_medical.setText("");
        String line = "";
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            loadText.add(line);
        }public void loadList(){

        String loadedText = String.valueOf(loadText.get(0));
        String rname = "Hello: Name";
        String helloName [] = rname.split("Hello: ");
        //String nameToText [] = loadedText.split("");

        for(int i = 0; i < loadText.size(); i++){
            editText_name.setText(String.valueOf(loadText.get(0).split("Name:")));

        }
        //set all the editText values accordingly
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error " + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put your code in the question. You can add the picture if it helps to understand the warning, but the warning is produced by the code.

Comment: `@NonNull` is quite explicit - it just means that the `String` passed in cannot be null i.e. if you create a string variable, and there's a possibility it may not be initialised and you use that in your `.split()` call then it will not allow it.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider sorry, I added it now. I want to say that I did also initialise load text outside at the 'private ArrayList<String> loadText;' And 'editText_name.setText(String.valueOf(loadText.get(0)));' gets the whole string on that line which would be "Name: Jack Smith" for example. But as soon as I put '.split("Name: ") it goes black instead of green.

Comment: @MarkKeen No it does not, it just does that '@NonNull' thing as shown in the picture even when I did it with the 'String helloName [] = rname.split("Hello: ");'. Doesn't go red, or throw an error when running it. Just returns a weird string like "[Ljava.lang.string;@1488d068"

Comment: It is showing you the method parameters in a toolltip - I can't undrstand what you are trying to do, you are splitting a string, then making into a `String[]` - back to a `String` - `String.valueOf()` - this will return the `String[]` Object name ? Just use `.replaceAll("Name:", "");` - the reason why its that colour is because if you follow the source for setText() it is expecting a `CharSequence`.  BTW your setting the same text in a loop the size of your Array? i.e. if your Array has a size of 200, you'll be setting the same text 200 times.

Comment: @MarkKeen yeah, I realised that I just put it in there by accident, I also realised I'm meant to just get the second part of whatever goes after `Name: ` so I done that now like so: `String arrayS = String.valueOf(loadText.get(0));
                String parts [] = arrayS.split("Name: ");
                String part2 = parts[1];
                editText_name.setText(part2);` and it works fine now but it is still black between the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no string you have entered that would satisfy "Name: " in

```
"Hello: Name"
```

And I think what you want in your for loop is not element 0 all the time for your arraylist, it should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < loadText.size(); i++){
        editText_name.setText(String.valueOf(loadText.get(i).split("Hello: ")));

    }
```

But the more correct way would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < loadText.size(); i++){
        editText_name.setText(String.valueOf(loadText.get(i).replace("Hello: ")));

    }
```

If you just wanted the name.

However I think the problem with not retrieving the values is you have to add:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out) {
   out.putStringArrayList("loadValues", loadValues);
}
```

and to retrieve them:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle in) {
    loadValues = in.getStringArrayList("loadValues");

    //call method to set values again
}
```